# Laravel filtering a hasMany relation

Tags: php, laravel, filter

Background first on my question. A user hasMany `contacts` and a `contact` hasMany `anniversaries`. I want to filter the upcoming anniversaries. So far I have this:

```
$filtered = auth()->user()->contacts()->get()->each(function ($contact) {
    $contact->anniversaries->filter(function ($anniversary) {

        // return true or false based on a method on the anniversary model
        return $anniversary->method() == true;

    });
});
```

But this just returns all the contacts (obviously) with all their anniversaries, and I wish to exclude the ones that are false when calling the `$anniversary->method()`.

Whatever is in the `$anniversary->method()` is not important, this just returns a `true` or `false`.

When I do the following, it works:

```
$collection = auth()->user()->anniversaries()->get();

$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($anniversary) {
    return $anniversary->method() == true;
});
```

I get only the anniversaries from where the `$anniversary->method()` is indeed `true`.

My question is mainly, why does this happen, I only want to understand it, not so much need an answer on how to make it work. Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example, you are only filtering the `anniversaries` of each contact. You are not filtering the `contacts` directly per see.

```
$filtered = auth()->user()->contacts()->get()->each(function ($contact) {
    // You are filtering only the anniversaries of each contact
    $anniversaries = $contact->anniversaries->filter(function ($anniversary) {
        return $anniversary->method() == true;

    });

    // over here you should get the same as in your second example
    dd($anniversaries);
});
```

In your second example you are doing the following pseudo-code:

1. Fetch all anniversaries of each user
2. Filter the anniversaries that matches `$anniversary->method() === true`

To get the same results in the first example you would have to use a combination of `filter` with `->count()`

```
$filtered = auth()->user()->contacts()->get()->filter(function ($contact) {
    $filteredByMethod = $contact->anniversaries->filter(function ($anniversary) {

        // return true or false based on a method on the anniversary model
        return $anniversary->method() == true;
    });

    return $filteredByMethod->count() > 0;
});
```

Which one is more performant is beyond the scope of this answer.

### Quick tip

The method `filter` from `Laravel's collections` needs to return a `truthy` value to be filtered by. Since your `method` returns `true or false` you can just call the method directly without comparing with `true`:

```
$collection = auth()->user()->anniversaries()->get();

$filtered = $collection->filter(function ($anniversary) {
    return $anniversary->method();
});
```